# Checking out a specific version of Angstrom

Tags: git, linux-kernel, beagleboard

I want to compile a Angstrom kernel from the source code.

I used

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tmlind/linux-omap-2.6.git linux-omap-2.6
```

to check out the latest kernel (2.6.38). But For some reason, I am not able to boot this kernel properly.

How can I check out the previous versions say 2.6.35.

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Git checkout works on both tags names and SHA numbers. I don't know the contents of the Linux Kernel, but I assume it uses tags to specify versions. Find out what tag you must use and simply do a 'git checkout tagname'.

Comment: Linux tags are just a `v` prepended to the version number, so in this case `git checkout v2.6.35`.